# Sinatra on Heroku - Custom rake assets:pecompile method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, sinatra, rake

I am more a Sinatra developer than Rails and have been deploying Sinatra applications to Heroku from some time. All the time I would compile the assets in a separate git branch and then push to Heroku.

But yesterday I noticed that Heroku calls `rake assets:precompile` even if the app is not a Ruby on Rails app. So I wrote renamed my rake task to it. How ever I am getting an error after `bundle install` in Heroku. Gist will be provided below.

The issue is with calling the `coffee` command and possibly with `sass` as well. I would like to know how I can get these methods in Heroku.

I am not very interested in using an asset pipeline and instead would like to have a custom solution. But if things fail I guess even that is an option.

#### I tried

I tried to add a package.json with the hope that it will install coffee using npm. But was of no use.

`{
  "name": "umate-sinatra-websocket-chat",
  "version": "0.3.0",
  "dependencies": {
    "coffee-script": "~> 1.8.x"
  }
}`

#### Error I receive in `git push heroku`

```
Fetching repository, done.
Counting objects: 678, done.
Delta compression using up to 8 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (624/624), done.
Writing objects: 100% (678/678), 994.46 KiB | 111.00 KiB/s, done.
Total 678 (delta 203), reused 0 (delta 0)

-----> Ruby app detected
-----> Compiling Ruby/Rack
-----> Using Ruby version: ruby-2.1.4
-----> Installing dependencies using 1.6.3
       Running: bundle install --without development:test --path vendor/bundle --binstubs vendor/bundle/bin -j4 --deployment
       Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/..........
       Using eventmachine 1.0.3
       Using websocket-driver 0.4.0
       Installing method_source 0.8.2
       Installing coderay 1.1.0
       Installing slop 3.6.0
       Using rack 1.5.2
       Using redis 3.1.0
       Using tilt 1.4.1
       Installing backports 3.6.3
       Using bundler 1.6.3
       Using faye-websocket 0.8.0
       Installing multi_json 1.10.1
       Using puma 2.9.2
       Installing rack-flash3 1.0.5
       Using rack-protection 1.5.3
       Installing temple 0.6.10
       Using sinatra 1.4.5
       Installing rack-test 0.6.2
       Installing pry 0.10.1
       Installing sinatra-partial 0.4.0
       Installing sinatra-redirect-with-flash 0.2.1
       Installing slim 2.1.0
       Installing sinatra-contrib 1.4.2
       Your bundle is complete!
       Gems in the groups development and test were not installed.
       It was installed into ./vendor/bundle
       Bundle completed (7.13s)
       Cleaning up the bundler cache.
-----> Precompiling assets
       Running: rake assets:precompile
       coffee --compile --output src/public/assets/js/coffeescript src/assets/javascripts/
       rake aborted!
       Command failed with status (127): [coffee --compile --output src/public/asset...]
       /tmp/build_2072d43187393047978418079031274c/build/rake/assets.rake:8:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
       Tasks: TOP => assets:precompile
       (See full trace by running task with --trace)
 !
 !     Precompiling assets failed.
 !

 !     Push rejected, failed to compile Ruby app

To git@heroku.com:umate-chat.git
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'git@heroku.com:umate-chat.git'
```

This is the `Rake` task I am trying to run.

```
namespace :assets do

  desc "Compile all assets the their respective locations" # {{{
  task :precompile do |t|

    # Compile coffee script
    sh "coffee --compile --output src/public/assets/js/coffeescript src/assets/javascripts/"
    sh "sass --load-path src --update src/assets/stylesheets:src/public/assets/css/sass"

  end # }}}
end # }}}
```

Comment: I don't understand why you're against using an asset pipeline or a script that does this locally?

Comment: Asset pipeline is more or less dropped by project definition. Its stands at the last option. Even compiling locally and pushing is an issue because `rake assets:precompile` is expected to do some thing. While I might be able to do some conditional and respond to Heroku differently, I am curious on the matter on how to use `CoffeeScritp` in Heroku.

Comment: I precompile locally, I see no advantage to doing it on the server. If Heroku is running that Rake task then you could make it a no-op if it's production.